# Configurable Product CSV Import - Simples not associating

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, csv

I've been trying to import some configurable products via the csv importer in magento ce 2.2.3.

After running the import all products appear in the admin, however if I edit the configurable product, none of the simple products are associated.

Additionally if I then save the configurable product, it changes to a simple.

Here is a sample of my csv (where my multilple value delimiter is ';'):

```
allow_backorders,product_online,weight,tax_class_name,store_view_code,product_websites,manage_stock,attribute_set_code,product_type,sku,childrens_clothes_size,configurable_variations,barcode,season,description,short_description,fabric,name,clothing_type,color_name,colors,rrp,price,cost,has_options,is_coming_soon,is_in_stock,visibility,category_ids,_super_attribute_code,base_image,small_image,thumbnail,additional_images
1,1,1,Taxable Goods,,wholesale;wholesale_eu;wholesale_us,1,Children's Clothes,simple,TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-6M-WHT,0-6m,,5055604860593,Spring/Summer,,,,COCONUTS All over printed Tootsa Tots body/White (Hawaiian) 0-6m,Body,White (Hawaiian),White,19,9.5,5.77,0,0,1,Not Visible Individually,,,,,,
1,1,1,Taxable Goods,,wholesale;wholesale_eu;wholesale_us,1,Children's Clothes,simple,TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-12M-WHT,6-12m,,5055604860609,Spring/Summer,,,,COCONUTS All over printed Tootsa Tots body/White (Hawaiian) 6-12m,Body,White (Hawaiian),White,19,9.5,5.77,0,0,1,Not Visible Individually,,,,,,
1,1,1,Taxable Goods,,wholesale;wholesale_eu;wholesale_us,1,Children's Clothes,simple,TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-18M-WHT,12-18m,,5055604860616,Spring/Summer,,,,COCONUTS All over printed Tootsa Tots body/White (Hawaiian) 12-18m,Body,White (Hawaiian),White,19,9.5,5.77,0,0,1,Not Visible Individually,,,,,,
1,1,1,Taxable Goods,,wholesale;wholesale_eu;wholesale_us,1,Children's Clothes,simple,TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-24M-WHT,18-24m,,5055604860623,Spring/Summer,,,,COCONUTS All over printed Tootsa Tots body/White (Hawaiian) 18-24m,Body,White (Hawaiian),White,19,9.5,5.77,0,0,1,Not Visible Individually,,,,,,
1,1,1,Taxable Goods,,wholesale;wholesale_eu;wholesale_us,1,Children's Clothes,configurable,TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-WHT,,"sku=TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-6M-WHT,childrens_clothes_size=0-6m;sku=TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-12M-WHT,childrens_clothes_size=6-12m;sku=TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-18M-WHT,childrens_clothes_size=12-18m;sku=TM-SS19-TT-BD-COC-24M-WHT,childrens_clothes_size=18-24m",,Spring/Summer,,"Beautifully soft, pre-washed 100% organic Cotton jersey body with an envelope neck and nickel-free, coated snap buttons to make dressing easy. Choose from 3 striking prints and colour options, including this hand painted, Hawaiian shirt style design on fresh bright white.",100% Organic Cotton (GOTS Certified),COCONUTS All over printed Tootsa Tots body/White (Hawaiian),Body,White (Hawaiian),White,19,9.5,5.77,1,1,1,"Catalog, Search","Baby & Toddler/Bodies, Rompers & Pyjamas",childrens_clothes_size,/Sketch_Coconuts_Body_White.jpg,/Sketch_Coconuts_Body_White.jpg,/Sketch_Coconuts_Body_White.jpg,/Sketch_Coconuts_Body_White.jpg
```

Any assistance gratefully received!

Comment: have you done `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` after import?

Comment: Yes, tried that and clearing caches but neither work.

Comment: So I have re-run my imports and I can see all of the new products in the admin. However still if I edit a configurable product, it gets changed to a simple, and also none of the simples are associated.

Comment: You can find detailed configurable products import guide on our blog and also working CSV examples https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-configurable-products.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try this CSV, download from this link - https://ufile.io/8cqd0

Comment: The only significant difference I see there is the additional_attributes column, but the documentation suggests you can replace this with a column for each attribute which is what I have done (eg: color_name, clothing_type...). The strange thing is that I have already imported a few hundred products using the same base csv, so I'm not sure what is causing the problems this time around.

Comment: Can you please share your file?

Comment: It is what I have pasted in the original question.